# IIS 7 IP changed to machine name

Tags: iis-7, ip, windows-server-2008

I am having an issue with my server switching from using the IP address to machine name.

Yesterday, I went into IIS 7 and created a new application under the Default Web Site. I gave it an alias (i.e. forschung) and gave it the Physical Path (a bin-debug file in the Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 folder). I did this as per suggestion on the GIS API documentation. Then, I changed the Flex project'S Output folder to bin-debug and Output folder to http:///forschung. I was able to successfully run the project in Google Chrome, but was experincing errors in Firefox. After changing the REST service paths to use the machine name (instead of the IP address), I no longer had issues in Firefox. However, now it appears that my REST services, and my other applications, need to be changed to use the machine name, but I want to keep using the IP address since changing the services and applications would take a lot of time. What do I need to do to use the IP address again?

I am using IIS 7 on a Windows Server Standard 2008 machine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a previously created Website which was competeing with the Default Web Site. As soon as the competing website was removed, everything was fixed.